# What is this android ui element called?

Tags: android, android-xml, material-components-android

Currently, I am trying to create a UI for my app and came across a design of the Amazon Android app. I was very interested in the following:

[image]

My question now is: What does this UI element consist of? I would have thought of two CardViews within one Cardview. This is my current approach:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cvAddress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/color_user_address_border"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/margin_right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/margin_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:strokeWidth="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:strokeWidth="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]

It's pretty close, but my border is much thicker and looks kinda ugly.

### Edit: Finished XML Layout

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cvAddress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background_address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/margin_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/margin_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUserDataAddressHeadline">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Add new Address"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_big"
            app:drawableTint="@color/color_text_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_divider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvShippingAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Shipping Addresses"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_big"
            app:drawableTint="@color/color_text_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddAddress" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_divider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBillingAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Billing Addresses"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_big"
            app:drawableTint="@color/color_text_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingAddress" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Pictures

Clicking first item

[image]

Clicking second item

[image]

Clicking third item

[image]

Comment: This is just a Simple View group with a custom drawable and TextViews with  `drawableEnd` since there is no Elevation there is no need to use `CardView`.

Comment: You don't need to do so much nesting there... Either use a single vertical linear layout with TextViews inside (using drawableEnd), or use a ConstraintLayout and add the Textviews (and optionally imageViews as well, if you need more control over the image). You can use a cardView if you want, but the only child of the CardView should be either 1 ConstraintLayout or 1 LinearLayout... no other viewGroup should be needed/desired.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini But I want each item to be clickable? How to achieve this without nesting?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your confusion (see what I did?). Each Widget/View regardless of what it is, can be "clickable" and have the "animation" (Ripple) as you call it. A `ViewGroup` (ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout, etc.) is just "a view that can _group_ more views" but they are, themselves, also views and as such, also "clickable" if you so desire. Having said this, if you want each item to be clickable, you need to assign a Click Listener to each of them as you would normally do regardless of which level of nesting they have. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, but what I don't understand is how to group these three sections inside my cardview. Every section itself should have a ripple effect and not the entire cardview itself. I updated current edit

Comment: I believe that `clickable` is also true by default or at least if you assign a click listener you don't need to add it. Focusable is fine, especially if you're dealing with Accessibility and want the "screen reader" to be able to focus the item (to read its `contentDescription` via TalkBack).

Comment: Assign the click listener (and the foreground) to the ConstraintLayouts you have there, instead of the whole cardView.

Comment: Sry, I don't know how to do this better than my current "finished layout". If you have the time, you can maybe optimize it.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thank you very much, didn't know I could design that. I updated my final flattened layout. Looks great, performs well and works!

Comment: You're welcome and good job in taking the trip to understand the various differences in each case. I don't think you need the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingAddress"` (for each Divider). You already have `Top to bottom` so that should be enough, since the view is `1dp` tall and that's enough information for the Algorithm to position and size all views. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your border is "much thicker" because you have two cardviews there I think.

I would *not* make the internal items a Cardview. You can have the rounded external border with a CardView or with any ViewGroup and a background with a rounded corner.

The items inside are/could/should be normal TextViews with a "drawable end" set to the disclosure triangle/arrow/caret (you name it).

You can make each item a ConstraintLayout and have two separate widgets as well (a TextView and an Image View) for much granular control.

#### UPDATE

Based on your final design, I made some changes.

Here's how it looks in the editor:

[image: Image of Android Layout with three rows and rounded corners]

The key to *not* use the *uneeded* `CardView` is to give the replacing layout (a ConstraintLayout) a background with rounded corners.

To do so, create a Drawable (in the res/drawable folder), I called mine for this example "`rounded_background.xml`".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Tweak at will.

I then, modified your Layout to be a bit "flatter".

Because you want each individual item to be clickable and have its own "ripple boundaries" You can wrap the Text/Images in their own ConstraintLayout.

So Version 1, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutGroupAndRippleEffectOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Meine Bestellungen"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vBorderOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayoutGroupAndRippleEffectOne" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutGroupAndRippleEffectTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vBorderOne">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Spar-Abo-Artikel"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTwo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewTwo"
            app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vBorderTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayoutGroupAndRippleEffectTwo" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutGroupAndRippleEffectThree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vBorderTwo">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Adressen"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewThree"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewThree"
            app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(NOTE: I replaced all your local stuff with colors/icons from "android").

The hierarchy here is:

```
CL
 CL1
  TV + IV
 DIVIDER
 CL2
  TV + IV
 DIVIDER
 CL3
  TV + IV
CL
```

If you didn't need to modify the ImageView (or provide special click to the actual image view that is different from the actual text view... you could flatten this even further into something like

```
CL
  TV1
  DIVIDER
  TV2
  DIVIDER
  TV3
CL
```

It would be more like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Meine Bestellungen"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:drawableTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vBorderOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewOne" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Spar-Abo-Artikel"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vBorderOne"
        app:drawableTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vBorderTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewTwo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Adressen"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vBorderTwo"
        app:drawableTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which looks like:

[image: Similar image as before]

I didn't play with margins/paddings/etc. but you get the idea.

This is "better" in the sense that you only have a bunch of flat views.

Honestly, the TextView image (drawableEnd/Start/Top/Bottom) is a lot less customizable than a regular ImageView but if all you need is a icon, it can work for you.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible with this approach to be able to click the items inside the cardview? E.g "Meine Bestellung" and "Spar-Abo-Artikel" should be clickable

Comment: Absolutely possible. Give each item its "Id" and using Viewbinding (or findViewById) get their references.

Comment: ok, I will try your approach and post the code

Comment: I tried using ConstraintLayout as items inside the cardview, but "android:focusable" and "android:clickable" are not working with constraintlayout. Every time I click on one of the items, no animation is shown. Edited my code

Comment: What do you mean by _animation_? The _Ripple_ effect?

Comment: Yes, the ripple effect. No difference between "android:focusable=true" or false

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. I will post the code

Comment: use `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to make it happen on the views that need it.